# How to remove the Linux icon despite the Docker application

Tags: windows, docker, icons

A while ago, I downloaded the Docker program, but I did not use it, so I deleted it, but since that day my device started slowing down and this icon appeared. I thought that the reason was Docker because it produced a hyper-v problem that disabled my Virgoal Box. Do you have any previous experience?

This icon has no properties
[image]

Comment: have you solved it yet?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by the following steps;

Open PowerShell and type;

wsl --unregister docker-desktop-data

wsl --unregister docker-desktop

(This removed the two data icons)

Then to remove the Linux Icon -> Open Settings -> Control Panel -> Programs and Features ->

(Top Left) Turn Windows features on or off...

Untick Windows Subsystem for Linux

This will force a reboot and the icon is then gone